# How to embed SWT browser in an Eclipse view?

Tags: java, browser, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to display the `SWT` browser just like an opened file tabbed in the Eclipse text Editor. My current implementation captures the `shell` of the `TextEditor` and blocks the editor which is not desirable.

```
Shell parentShell=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getSite().getShell();
Shell myShell = new Shell (parentShell, SWT.EMBEDDED);
myShell.setLayout (new FillLayout()); 
Browser mybrowser = new Browser (myShell, SWT.NONE);
```

Comment: this link may help http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html

Comment: also this http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t28993.html

Comment: Do you really want to do this independent of which editor is open? Note that "an opened file tabbed in the Eclipse text Editor" doesn't really make sense -- each tab is its own editor.

Comment: @Rachel, I did a lot of googling and already checked those links but they are not what I want.

Comment: @Alexey, I want to open the file in the text editor of Java perspective, the one generally used for coding